# Using TFS without Visual Studio

Tags: svn, tfs

Is there some setting in the workspace setup that allows you to edit the files, and have TFS determine what has changed?

I'm working with Matlab code that we would like to have checked in, but since we don't use Visual Studio for that it makes working complicated. (checkout each file we want to edit).

Maybe like Subversion, but we don't have the choice to use another source control system.

Comment: 2012, so I think the answer selected below should work for us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Team Foundation Server 2012 introduced the concept of [local workspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx). This allows you to work with your files without explicitly having to checkout files before edit.

If you install the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) you get integration into Windows Explorer for commands like Get Latest and Checkin.

Comment: I like some of the other, but this is the most universal.

Answer (score 4):

The PowerTools for TFS have explorer integration (similar to TortoiseSVN) but I never found them to work very well, when you see them flickering away and using up lots of CPU you lose confidence.

You can use the [TFS Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776) tool, which is basically a cut-down Visual Studio. Its not nice when you're used to better tools, but this is what happens when you have a tool that is so very tightly integrated to VS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TFS from command-line. The `tf.exe` command-line tool is located in `%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\`, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe`.

See MSDN article ["Command-line tools for TFS | Use Team Foundation version control command"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e) to learn about using TFS command-line tool.

Comment: I think this requires visual studio to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Your have several options for working with TFS from outside visual studio.

You mention that you use MatLab, so my first suggestion is to use the MSSCCI Provider found on visual studio gallery. The MSSCCI Provider enables you to have direct TFS integration (source control only) from within MatLab. Here is the link for the x86 version: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/06c8e056-7f77-4a5c-9b8b-49318c143df8. Remember to use the x64 version for MatLab 64-bit.

Your other options are using the commandline either directly using tf.exe or the tfpt.exe which is part of the TFS Power Tools pack.

The Power Tools pack also has a windows shell integration, kinda like Tourtoise SVN, so you can interact with source control directly from windows explorer.

Comment: I didn't know about this direct integration with Matlab. I will look into this for our devs who are using Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

have you got the power tools (tfpt) installed? you can checkout/in from the Explorer window then.

ALso, in VS under tools>options>sourceControl>environment there's some "check out automatically" options there that I've got set so I don't have to manually checkout a file I'm going to edit